# jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table doesn't exist in database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, repository

I'm developing a web app using SpringBoot, and this is my `application.properties` file to specify the credentials to access to the database:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Salamander
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

but when I try to run the SpringBoot app, it gives me this error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'salamander.user' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor72.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

Of course I've an entity called user, but the database is empty. But

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

should say to hibernate to create the tables again in the db, right? So what's the problem?

If I do the same but with a remote database, it works, even if the remote db is empty.

Comment: did u manage to fix ur prblm ?

Comment: @FuSsA I think the problem was this statement `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`, which I removed and it started to work...

Comment: It should correspond the dialect you expect to be used, for example org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect worked perfectly for me. Also make sure you don't use any of the deprecated dialect classes here.

Comment: Hi @nbro , I'am getting 
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'springboot.batch_job_instance' doesn't exist

Do you have any idea on this issue?

Comment: @BandhamManikanta Sorry, man, I have not used Spring for a while. Maybe ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

this issue was fixed by removing 
**spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialec‌​t**